# SoC EDS DS-5 installation on Linux

Tags: eclipse, ds-5

I am trying to install EDS DS-5 18.1 on my Linux 16.04 machine but after installation, I can't run it (not at all even from terminal window).
The error message is:

> the expected Ds-5 environment has not been configured. Please ensure
>   Eclipse is started using the correct executable so that the
>   environment is automatically configured.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the problem was simple and I just noticed it in DS-5 examples which can be found in directory: C:\altera\18.1\embedded\examples\software...

DS-5 must be launched from the SoC EDS Command Shell in order to have all environment variables properly set up.  Launch the SoC EDS Command Shell in Windows by selecting Altera  -> SoC Embedded Design Suite ->    SoC EDS  Command Shell.

In Linux, run embedded_command_shell.sh found in the linux64 directory. (Do not source the .sh, simply type its name at the prompt.)